# Windows Server 2008 R2 and IIS7: Is there a default upload limit for FTP sites?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I created an FTP site on a dedicated server and got the user to connect right away. Still, when uploading a large file the upload speed doesn't go higher than 27 kb/s, I thought the problem was at my end but when I tried with another server I got a much higher speed for the same file.  So I'm guessing there's a default bandwidth limit hidden somewhere, or should I open a support ticket with my provider?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like speed throttling somewhere. Do you notice slow connections to your server with other protocols, IE like HTTP. Because you were able to upload faster to another server, it sounds like the issue is somewhere in your providers network. I would open a support ticket